# Facebook Messanger Bot Webhook issue

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I received this message

> Your Webhooks subscription callback URL has not been accepting
>   updates.
>
> We've noticed that your Webhooks subscription for callback URL
>   https://trololo.herokuapp.com/bot has not been accepting updates
>   for at least 16 minutes. Please verify that your callback server is
>   functioning so you may continue to receive updates. If you need to
>   update your callback URL, see
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions#update
>
> If your callback URL continues to fail to accept updates for 8 hours
>   straight, we will disable your subscription. To reactivate the
>   subscription, make a POST request with the same parameters, and it
>   will be reactivated.

This code is executed on the server

```
app.post('/bot', function (req, res) {
  console.log('post bot: ' + req);
  var messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
  for (var i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
    var event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
    var sender = event.sender.id;
    if (event.message && event.message.text) {
      text = event.message.text;
      console.log('text received: ' + text);
      sendTextMessage(sender, "Text received, echo: "+ text.substring(0, 200));
    }
  }
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

But it fails because `req.body` is undefined. The req params is also no json because it makes this error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

req only shows [object Object] and I have no idea whats inside the object. .toString isn't working either.

I made the complete guide twice. I think the issue comes from the part were the facebook page should connect to the facebook app. I do this with `curl -ik -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=<mytoken>"` Please help. Any response is greatly appreciated.

Here is a demo log
[image: error logs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a dependency problem... maybe you're missing the json body parser `body-parser`

If you look at comments on program sample on `node-wit/examples/messenger.js`, you will see that you need install some deps:

in your project directory, try:

```
npm install body-parser express request
```

And look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFO1cRr5-qY ... I think they resolved exactly this issue and others that you may find.